# Why is this command deleting all entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to remove a specific, named, item if it is dropped on the floor. I have the following on my command block:

```
kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"RedFlag"}}}
```

But it's removing *all* items, not just the one I want. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried

```
kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"red_flower",Damage:2}}
```

But that didn't work either, it's still removing all items, even things that aren't red flowers!

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a way of doing this in my head, and the only thing I can think of is 1) give the items a custom name or 2) give the item a score.  Can item entities even have a score though?

Comment: @MBraedley I've given them a custom name, but that requires all the {tag stuff}

Comment: You should be able to use `e[name=<name>]`.  At least I think you can do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/kill` command does not support killing objects (not yet anyway) who fit through a NBT citeria. Only identifiers with the `@e` command will be considered.

When you entered:

```
kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"RedFlag"}}}
kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"red_flower",Damage:2}}
```

It is considered as:

```
kill @e[type=Item]
kill @e[type=Item]
```

Regardless of how much NBT data an object has, it'll always kill all the entities of the type specified.

---

This means that `/kill @e[type=Sheep] {CustomName:"Sheep"}` will kill all sheep(s) in the world. Even if they have/don't have the custom name "Sheep", or a completely different name altogether.
*Think about all the sheeps! (Those loaded in anyway)*

Comment: According to the wiki, you're correct.

Comment: Nope. I've tested it. It doesn't take that long to type (and use): `/summon Sheep ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"No. 1"}`, `/summon Sheep ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"No. 2"}` and `/kill @e[type=Sheep] {CustomName:"No. 1"}`.

Comment: Shucks. I guess I'll have to do it a different way!

Comment: You could always use an item dropper system to identify the items (though putting them back where they were will be a problem).

Comment: @fredley Use `scoreboard` command to match NBT and then do `kill @e[score_name=X,score_name_min=X]`

Comment: Note that `/kill` with NBT does work in Minecraft 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it by using the new `/execute` command;

1. Give the item you want to remove a scoreboard objective: `/scoreboard objectives add RedFlag dummy RedFlag`
2. Set the score for the item to 1: `/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,r=5] RedFlag 1`
3. Than use this command:
   `/execute @e[score_RedFlag=1,score_RedFlag_min=1,type=Item] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[r=0,type=Item]`

Maybe if you use this it will work.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you haven't tested this for yourself?  Before you give an answer, you should test it to see if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Very few data tags can be used to select entities, and the format you are trying is not how it works. Try:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,c=1] {CustomName:"killitem"}
```

and then

```
/kill@e[name=killitem]
```

The selector `c=1` in the first command could be changed to match the amount of items you want to name.